# signalr using custom membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

So I have implemented my own custom membership provider, currently only overwriting ValidateUser(). I also have signalr working, currently just a simple method that calls send message and then sends it out to all listeners. I would like to add some validation checking so that this command cannot be run on its own. So far I have found you can do this using: Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

```
[HubName("messageController")]
public class MessageController : Hub
{
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)      // this line not working
        {
            Clients.addMessage(message);
        }
        else
        {
            Clients.addMessage("not authenticated");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem though is because I am currently using a custom membership provider value is false. Is there something else I should be using here instead?

Currently when I Login I execute:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            // Need something here to actually set the logged in user
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "");
    }
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to store my own code to handle the session, I tried using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);` which worked but I'm pretty sure its wrong. When I tried to introduce Roles by changing it to `Context.User.IsInRole("Admin")` it returned false. even though I used the below User model (which when debugging never gets to this method):

```
public class User : IPrincipal
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    public long UserID;
    public string Name;
    public string ConnectionId;

    public virtual IIdentity Identity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
       return true;
    }
```

}

I'm pretty confident I am missing something with this, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` after you've validated the user is perfectly OK, the default `AccountController` created by the MVC3 template does exactly the same.

The reason why your call to `Context.User.IsInRole()` doesn't work is because that won't invoke your custom `User` class (the framework doesn't know about it), instead it will try to get the roles via a `RoleProvider`. You need to build a custom provider and hook it up in the Web.config like you did with the membership provider.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I actually implemented this before I saw the comment but thank you. The only other thing that was confusing is when you call `Context.User.IsInRole()` it calls `RoleProvider.GetRolesForUser` it does not call `RoleProvider.IsUserInRole()`